# How can I make a sub-gui(?) inside a gui?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I want to make a sub-gui(i know this isn't the correct term, but I want to know the correct term)

in a VC++ windows form

I'm making a GUI that replicates the windows system, so you click start and the start menu pops up, so I want it to be inside the main gui, but on top of it,  so it moves with the main gui (if the program is moved/minimized/etc..

Is there a way to do this?
Am I going about this with the right mindset, or is there another way to do it?

Thankyou

Cain

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I have no idea how to put a GUI on top of(and inside) a GUI?

Comment: I don't even know what term to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help, it's called MDI (Multiple Document Interface) it will allow you to create child forms inside a parent form:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx